# iOS - Language switcher in app | Content not appearing when language is not set on English (US)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've got a language switcher which was working pretty good until I got a mail from a user saying that my app couldn't load any content.

After a bit of chatting, user told me that they had their iDevice language set on English (UK). 
I told them to change it to English (US), and the app then worked as expected.

**Now**

My app falls back on English language (and content) when the device language is other than English or Italian by default, but I don't really understand why it wouldn't work when having language set other than English(US).

Here's the code I'm using to load the Settings page (a plist file)

```
+ (NSArray*)readSettingsPlist{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Settings.plist"];

    NSBundle *bundle;

    UALog(@"%@",[NSLocale preferredLanguages]);

    if ([[NSLocale preferredLanguages] containsObject:@"en"] || [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] containsObject:@"it"]){
        bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0] ofType:@"lproj"]];
    }
    else{
        bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"en" ofType:@"lproj"]];
    }


    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath])
    {
        plistPath = [bundle pathForResource:@"Settings" ofType:@"plist"];
    }

    return [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

}
```

On my device and even on the simulator it's working fine, but I would like to know if there's any way to improve this piece of code in order to allow people with device language other than English (US) to load content properly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two questions:

1) How does a plist end up in the `NSDocumentDirectory`?  Is it copied there after it is found?  Why wouldn't you just use the file in the Main Bundle?  That file will always have precedence, even if a different language is selected after the app is launched.

2) What happens if `[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0]` isn't `@"en"` or `@"it"`?  Then you may have a bundle path that is nil (you haven't mentioned other .lproj directories besides `@"en"` or `@"it"`.

I might do something like this

```
for (NSString* lang in [NSLocale preferredLanguages])
{
     bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0] ofType:@"lproj"]]; 
     if (bundle) break;
}
//fallback to @"en" if bundle is still nil
if (!bundle) 
{
     bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"en" ofType:@"lproj"]];
}
```

Comment: 1) Yes, it gets copied first, I've done it because I'm supporting both Italian and English in my app, so I was kinda "forcing" files to be loaded from the documents directory basing on the language chosen from the app.
2) Exactly what I was trying to do, fallback on English locale by default, independently from the user's device language


I'll try your code and let you know.

Comment: I solved this exact problem in a large production app in this manner: 1) save the discovered locale string in an `NSUserDefaults`.  2) In the app delegate `applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application`  check to see if the saved locale is the same as the detected locale.  If its not, reset everything and use the new locale settings.  This prevents you from having to copy the file to documents directory and also allows the user to change the language after the initial launch of the app.